# Understanding Data Leakage and getting perfect score by exploiting test data

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have read an article on data leakage. In a hackathon there are two sets of data, train data on which participants train their algorithm and test set on which performance is measured.
Data leakage helps in getting a perfect score in test data, with out viewing train data by exploiting the leak.
I have read the article, but I am missing the crux how the leakage is exploited. 
Steps as shown in article are following:

#### Let's load the test data.

Note, that we don't have any training data here, just test data. Moreover, we will not even use any features of test objects. All we need to solve this task is the file with the indices for the pairs, that we need to compare.
Let's load the data with test indices.

```
test = pd.read_csv('../test_pairs.csv')
test.head(10)

  pairId    FirstId SecondId
0   0       1427    8053
1   1       17044   7681
2   2       19237   20966
3   3       8005    20765
4   4       16837   599
5   5       3657    12504
6   6       2836    7582
7   7       6136    6111
8   8       23295   9817
9   9       6621    7672

test.shape[0]
368550
```

For example, we can think that there is a test dataset of images, and each image is assigned a unique Id from 0 to N−1 (N -- is the number of images). In the dataframe from above FirstId and SecondId point to these Id's and define pairs, that we should compare: e.g. do both images in the pair belong to the same class or not. So, for example for the first row: if images with Id=1427 and Id=8053 belong to the same class, we should predict 1, and 0 otherwise.
But in our case we don't really care about the images, and how exactly we compare the images (as long as comparator is binary).

```
 print(test['FirstId'].nunique())
 print(test['SecondId'].nunique())
 26325
 26310
```

So the number of pairs we are given to classify is very very small compared to the total number of pairs.
To exploit the leak we need to assume (or prove), that the total number of positive pairs is small, compared to the total number of pairs. For example: think about an image dataset with 1000 classes, N images per class. Then if the task was to tell whether a pair of images belongs to the same class or not, we would have 1000*N*(N−1)/2 positive pairs, while total number of pairs was 1000*N(1000N−1)/2.

Another example: in Quora competitition the task was to classify whether a pair of qustions are duplicates of each other or not. Of course, total number of question pairs is very huge, while number of duplicates (positive pairs) is much much smaller.

Finally, let's get a fraction of pairs of class 1. We just need to submit a constant prediction "all ones" and check the returned accuracy. Create a dataframe with columns pairId and Prediction, fill it and export it to .csv file. Then submit

```
 test['Prediction'] = np.ones(test.shape[0])
 sub=pd.DataFrame(test[['pairId','Prediction']])
 sub.to_csv('sub.csv',index=False)
 All ones have accuracy score is 0.500000.
```

So, we assumed the total number of pairs is much higher than the number of positive pairs, but it is not the case for the test set. It means that the test set is constructed not by sampling random pairs, but with a specific sampling algorithm. Pairs of class 1 are oversampled.
Now think, how we can exploit this fact? What is the leak here? If you get it now, you may try to get to the final answer yourself, othewise you can follow the instructions below.

#### Building a magic feature

In this section we will build a magic feature, that will solve the problem almost perfectly. The instructions will lead you to the correct solution, but please, try to explain the purpose of the steps we do to yourself -- it is very important.

#### Incidence matrix

First, we need to build an incidence matrix. You can think of pairs (FirstId, SecondId) as of edges in an undirected graph.
The incidence matrix is a matrix of size (maxId + 1, maxId + 1), where each row (column) i corresponds i-th Id. In this matrix we put the value 1to the position [i, j], if and only if a pair (i, j) or (j, i) is present in a given set of pais (FirstId, SecondId). All the other elements in the incidence matrix are zeros.
Important! The incidence matrices are typically very very sparse (small number of non-zero values). At the same time incidence matrices are usually huge in terms of total number of elements, and it is impossible to store them in memory in dense format. But due to their sparsity incidence matrices can be easily represented as sparse matrices. If you are not familiar with sparse matrices, please see wiki and scipy.sparse reference. Please, use any of scipy.sparseconstructors to build incidence matrix.
For example, you can use this constructor: scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data, (i, j))). We highly recommend to learn to use different scipy.sparseconstuctors, and matrices types, but if you feel you don't want to use them, you can always build this matrix with a simple for loop. You will need first to create a matrix using scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((M, N), [dtype]) with an appropriate shape (M, N) and then iterate through (FirstId, SecondId) pairs and fill corresponding elements in matrix with ones.

Note, that the matrix should be symmetric and consist only of zeros and ones. It is a way to check yourself.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import scipy.sparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = pd.read_csv('../test_pairs.csv')


x = test[['FirstId','SecondId']].rename(columns={'FirstId':'col1', 'SecondId':'col2'})
y = test[['SecondId','FirstId']].rename(columns={'SecondId':'col1', 'FirstId':'col2'})
comb = pd.concat([x,y],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(keep='first')

 comb.head()
   col1      col2
0  1427      8053
1  17044    7681
2  19237   20966
3  8005    20765
4  16837   599

 data = np.ones(comb.col1.shape, dtype=int)

 inc_mat = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data,(comb.col1,comb.col2)), shape=(comb.col1.max() + 1, comb.col1.max() + 1))

  rows_FirstId   = inc_mat[test.FirstId.values,:]
  rows_SecondId  = inc_mat[test.SecondId.values,:]
  f = rows_FirstId.multiply(rows_SecondId)
  f = np.asarray(f.sum(axis=1))
  f.shape
  (368550, 1)

  f = f.sum(axis=1)
  f = np.squeeze(np.asarray(f))
  print (f.shape)
```

#### Now build the magic feature

Why did we build the incidence matrix? We can think of the rows in this matix as of representations for the objects. i-th row is a representation for an object with Id = i. Then, to measure similarity between two objects we can measure similarity between their representations. And we will see, that such representations are very good.

Now select the rows from the incidence matrix, that correspond to test.FirstId's, and test.SecondId's.

So do not forget to convert `pd.series` to `np.array`

These lines should normally run very quickly

```
 rows_FirstId   = inc_mat[test.FirstId.values,:] 
 rows_SecondId  = inc_mat[test.SecondId.values,:]
```

Our magic feature will be the dot product between representations of a pair of objects. Dot product can be regarded as similarity measure -- for our non-negative representations the dot product is close to 0 when the representations are different, and is huge, when representations are similar.
Now compute dot product between corresponding rows in rows_FirstId and rows_SecondId matrices.

#### From magic feature to binary predictions

But how do we convert this feature into binary predictions? We do not have a train set to learn a model, but we have a piece of information about test set: the baseline accuracy score that you got, when submitting constant. And we also have a very strong considerations about the data generative process, so probably we will be fine even without a training set.
We may try to choose a thresold, and set the predictions to 1, if the feature value f is higer than the threshold, and 0 otherwise. What threshold would you choose?
How do we find a right threshold? Let's first examine this feature: print frequencies (or counts) of each value in the feature f.

For example use `np.unique` function, check for flags

Function to count frequency of each element

```
 from scipy.stats import itemfreq

 itemfreq(f)

 array([[    14, 183279],
        [    15,    852],
        [    19,    546],
        [    20, 183799],
        [    21,      6],
        [    28,     54],
        [    35,     14]])
```

Do you see how this feature clusters the pairs? Maybe you can guess a good threshold by looking at the values?
In fact, in other situations it can be not that obvious, but in general to pick a threshold you only need to remember the score of your baseline submission and use this information. 
Choose a threshold below:

```
      pred = f  > 14 # SET THRESHOLD HERE
      pred

      array([ True, False,  True, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)

      submission = test.loc[:,['pairId']]
      submission['Prediction'] = pred.astype(int)
      submission.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
```

I want to understand the idea behind this. How we are exploiting the leak from the test data only.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hint in the article. The number of positive pairs should be 1000*N*(N−1)/2, while the number of all pairs is 1000*N(1000N−1)/2. Of course, the number of all pairs is much, much larger if the test set was sampled at random.

As the author mentions, after you evaluate your constant prediction of 1s on the test set, you can tell that the sampling was not done at random. The accuracy you obtain is 50%. Had the sampling been done correctly, this value should've been much lower.

Thus, they construct the incidence matrix and calculate the dot product (the measure of similarity) between the representations of our ID features. They then reuse the information about the accuracy obtained with constant predictions (at 50%) to obtain the corresponding threshold (f > 14). It's set to be greater than 14 because that constitutes roughly half of our test set, which in turn maps back to the 50% accuracy.

The "magic" value didn't have to be greater than 14. It could have been equal to 14. You could have adjusted this value after some leader board probing (as long as you're capturing half of the test set).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate the following part , if possible with example : "Thus, they construct the incidence matrix and calculate the dot product (the measure of similarity) between the representations of our ID features. They then reuse the information about the accuracy obtained with constant predictions (at 50%) to obtain the corresponding threshold (f > 14). It's set to be greater than 14 because that constitutes roughly half of our test set, which in turn maps back to the 50% accuracy"....

Answer (score 0):

It was observed that the test data was not sampled properly; same-class pairs were oversampled. Thus there is a much higher probability of each pair in the training set to have target=1 than any random pair. This led to the belief that one could construct a similarity measure based only on the pairs that are present in the test, i.e., whether a pair made it to the test is itself a strong indicator of similarity.
Using this insight one can calculate an incidence matrix and represent each id `j` as a binary array (the `i`-th element representing the presence of i-j pair in test, and thus representing the strong probability of similarity between them). This is a pretty accurate measure, allowing one to find the "similarity" between two rows just by taking their dot product.
The cutoff arrived at is purely by the knowledge of target-distribution found by leaderboard probing.